# How can I count repeating characters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random, numbers

I made a random simulation of Roulette

```
set.seed(101)
n=10000


black <- sample("black",size=n, replace=TRUE)
red <- sample("red",size=n, replace=TRUE)
green <- sample("green",size=n, replace=TRUE)

roulette_table=matrix(NaN,n,1) 

for (i in 1:n) {
temp = runif(1, 0, 1) # uniform between 0 and 1
# determines the probability
if (temp<0.04) { 
  roulette_table [i,1]=green[i] 
} else if (temp>0.04 & temp<0.52) { 
  roulette_table[i,1]=red[i]
}  else  {
  roulette_table[i,1]=black[i] 
} 
  }
```

How can i count the frequency of repeating characters ?
Thanks

Comment: `sample("black",size=n, replace=TRUE)` is `"black"` repeated `n` times, you are sampling from a vector of length 1 :(. Hopefully, you won't run into memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is not an answer.

This is a much better way of running the same simulation. It is fully vectorized and much simpler and readable.

```
set.seed(101)

colrs <- c("green", "red", "black")

u <- runif(n, 0, 1)
i <- findInterval(u, c(0, 0.04, 0.52, Inf))
roultab <- matrix(colrs[i], ncol = 1)

identical(roulette_table, roultab)
#[1] TRUE
```

Then use the code in @akrun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60958230/8245406).

```
out <- rle(c(roultab))
out1 <- setNames(out$lengths, out$values)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rle`

```
out <- rle(roulette_table[,1])
out1 <- setNames(out$lengths, out$values)
head(out1)
#  red black   red black   red black 
#   1     3     2     3     5     8
```